# ValueError: Cell k2 doesn't contain an image

Tags: python, excel

I am stuck with this python code regarding `SheetImageLoader`. The error message says that there's no image in the cell I am referencing, but there's an image in that cell.

```py
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
import openpyxl

#ADD PICTURE TO PICBOX(TOPLEVEL)
def pic_upload():

    excel_path = ('DData.xlsx')
    file =openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)
    sheet=file['Sheet1']

    image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)           
    picget = image_loader.get('k2')
    picget.show
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
raise ValueError("Cell {} doesn't contain an image".format(cell))
ValueError: Cell k2 doesn't contain an image
```

Comment: I believe you should point to 'K2' (with upper 'K' instead of lower 'k')

Comment: Can't believe its that easy. Thank you it worked perfect

Comment: Openpyxl itself isn't case sensitive when it comes to coordinates. I'd suggest submitting a bug for the image loader library.